# несколько уведомлений в центре сообщений windows 10

Tags: wpf, winforms, mvvm

Проект на основе https://roundwide.com/implemen... -and-mvvm/. Иконка в трее и уведомления. Как сделать чтобы на каждый вновь сгенерированный baloontooltip в центре уведомлений добавлялось новое уведомление (например, как от почтовой программы на каждое новое пришедшее письмо)? Сейчас новое уведомление в центре уведомлений заменяет предыдущее.
Спасибо.

Comment: Балун != Тоаст, Win10 криво обрабатывает старые " baloon" уведомления, сама удаляя их/заменяя. В Win11 это поправили вроде как. Хотите "хорошо", берите WinApi и отправляйте Toast уведомления.

Comment: в другом пробном приложении работало, т.е. дело не в винде..

Comment: В каком другом, как там отображались уведомления? Может в том "пробном" всеж были тосты?

Comment: baloon'ы. проект на той же основе. уведомления были на каждый балун. потом стал пытаться повысить функциональность, кнопки там итп на уведомлениях. проект сломал и удалил )
вообще на данном этапе стоит задача выбора платформы и пакетов. нужно чтобы и на семерке приложение работало и на 10ке. и чтобы контролы были современные и нарядные.